# Authentication in Bluecove - Linux x64 not working

Tags: java, linux, bluecove

I'm having troubles trying to authenticate a BT device in a pairing process using Bluecove (both bluecove and bluecove-gpl 2.1.1 SNAPSHOT libraries) in Linux x64 with 64 bits JVM. While discovery seems to be fine, when trying to authenticate with known PIN, it never does, mostly, I'm afraid, because this functionality was never implmented.

This is the method that actually does the pairing:

```
public Boolean pairingDevice()
{
    //check if authenticated already
    if (remoteDevice.isAuthenticated()){
        return true;
    }
    else{

        LOG.info("--> Pairing device");

        try {
            PIN = "111111";
            boolean paired = RemoteDeviceHelper.authenticate(remoteDevice, PIN);                
            //LOG.info("Pair with " + remoteDevice.getFriendlyName(true) + (paired ? " succesfull" : " failed"));
            devicePaired = paired;
            if (devicePaired)
                LOG.info("--> Pairing successful with device " + remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
            else
                LOG.info("--> Pairing unsuccessful with device " + remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.info("--> Pairing unsuccessful with device " + remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
            devicePaired = false;
        }
        LOG.info("--> Pairing device Finish");
        return devicePaired;
    }
}
```

Now the call to

```
 boolean paired = RemoteDeviceHelper.authenticate(remoteDevice, PIN);
```

Ends up with a call to BluetoothStackBlueZ.authenticateRemoteDevice(long address, String passkey):

```
    /*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStack#authenticateRemoteDevice(long, java.lang.String)
 */
public boolean authenticateRemoteDevice(long address, String passkey) throws IOException {
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, this always returns FALSE, which results in undefined behaviour. Question is...what can I do to authenticate a remoteDevice in Linux using Bluecove?

Are there any alternatives to Bluecove? I've heard this same code works in Windows, but I really don't want to switch to Windows for this reason...

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Doesn't the documentation explicitly say that authentication (nor authorization nor encryption) is **not** implemented in `Bluecove`? https://code.google.com/archive/p/bluecove/wikis/Documentation.wiki

Answer (score 2):

For others running into same problems, I've tried this code in several platforms: Linux x64, Windows 7 64bits and never worked.

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 32 bits, installed:

libbluetooth-dev and bluez-utils

Worked perfectly...so my answer would be...use 32 bits if you need to use Bluecove. Whatever the reason this is not working on my Linux-Windows 64 machines...I don't know, but can't spend more time on this

Comment: As a side note, I should also say that I could only make it work using the bluecove and bluecovez SNAPSHOT libraries (http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/). The bluecove-gpl never worked for me, always failed when trying to pair devices. Besides bluecovez, you'll need libbluetooth-dev, bluez-utils, and dbus, hexdumd and unixsockets, you can find them here: http://code.google.com/p/blufeedme/source/browse/trunk/src/BlufeedmeBT/lib/?r . Besides, I always have to switch off/on everytime I try, or I'll get Inquiry Errors when searching devices or services....why?dunno

Comment: Completely understand if this was too long ago for you to able to help me, but I've been having the same problem and can't figure out how to get the non-gpl version running on my machine. I assume you meant the bluecove-bluez library as opposed to bluecovez (which doesn't appear in the snapshot link) but beyond that, how do you go about compiling it for the machine you're on? With the gpl version it was pretty simple using ant. Alternatively, did you find anything that worked better than bluecove?

Comment: Sorry @HarveyAdcock, I don't have the sources I've used for this neither the Bluetooth device I've used for this...so I cannot help :(